# Different Page heights in pageview flutter | is there a way to get overflow value

Tags: android, flutter, overflow, flutter-pageview

I am currently creating an application using flutter framework, and I am using page view for different part of the form, I have come a cross with this problem where my pages in page view have different height since they have different contents and some pages overflow.

Is there a way we can get the overflow value and put it on an a double / integer variable that I can assign to the height of the container?.

or

Is there any other way to deal with this problem

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 30),
    child: Container(
  height: _height, // variable for different height per page
  width: double.infinity,
  child: PageView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _pagecontroller,
    onPageChanged: (index){
      setState(() {
        page = index;
        isshown();
      });
    },
children: [
 Forms(...),/My different forms
 Forms(...),/My different forms
 Forms(...),/My different forms
 Forms(...), //My different forms 
]
),
```

[image: Sample form]
[image: Sample form]
[image: The Issue]

I have tried to assign a variable that changes that height per page, but it does work when used in different devices with different ratio/resolution/screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to Forms, so when exceeding the height limit of the container, scroll will be applied to the content.

```
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(...),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(...),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(...),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(...),
    )
  ],
```

Comment: How did I not think of this, Thank you very much Man!!